How to filter and clone HashMap in Rust?
I've got a simple task: filter existing HashMap and clone it into a new variable in Rust.
The code I've tried:
let numbers: HashMap<u32, u32> = HashMap::from([
    (1, 10),
    (2, 20),
    (3, 30),
]);

// Should retain only (2, 20)
let filtered: HashMap<u32, u32> = numbers
    .iter()
    .filter(|&(k, v)| *k < 3 && *v > 10)
    .cloned()
    .collect();

However, it doesn't compile:
error[E0271]: expected `Filter<Iter<'_, u32, u32>, {closure@main.rs:15:17}>` to be an iterator that yields `&_`, but it yields `(&u32, &u32)`
    --> src/main.rs:16:10
     |
16   |         .cloned()
     |          ^^^^^^ expected `&_`, found `(&u32, &u32)`
     |
     = note: expected reference `&_`
                    found tuple `(&u32, &u32)`
...


My colleague advised me with a working solution using filter_map:
let filtered: HashMap<u32, u32> = numbers
    .iter()
    .filter_map(|(k, v)| (*k < 3 && *v > 10).then_some((*k, *v)))
    .collect();

Note: you need to use .clone() instead of dereferencing in filter_map if you have a struct instead of primitive value.

Simply replace iter with into_iter() to create take owned values instead of references:
let filtered: HashMap<u32, u32> = numbers
    .into_iter()
    .filter(|&(k, v)| k < 3 && v > 10)
    .collect();
}

Attempt this online

This is better replaced by drain().

Thanks! It seems that I also have to add .clone() before into_iter() for struct values.
